# Outline polygon border that has been removed due to NA's

Tags: r, maps, shapefile, ggplot2

I want to plot a shape file using ggplot2 in R. More specifically, I want to plot % white living in each block for several major cities. So far, I've worked with New Haven. The problem is that some blocks are unpopulated, in which case % white = NA. Ggplot automatically draws these blocks in grey. I would like to draw them in white.

[New Haven with grey NAs](http://tinypic.com/r/2ngvnyc/6)

```
c_opts <- theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(), 
axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
axis.title.y=element_blank(), 
axis.ticks = element_blank(),
legend.text=element_text(size=10), 
legend.background=element_blank(), 
legend.key=element_rect(fill='transparent', colour=NA), 
panel.grid.major=element_line(colour='white'), 
panel.background=element_rect(fill='transparent', colour=NA),
legend.justification=c(0,0), 
legend.position=c(.15,.15),
legend.title=element_text(size=11, face='bold'))

map <- qplot(PolyCoordsY, PolyCoordsX, data=nh_geom, group=Poly_Name, fill = pc_nhwhite, geom="polygon", xlab = "", ylab = "", main = "New Haven") 
map + c_opts + scale_fill_gradient(name = "% White")
```

I can exclude the NAs by adding na.value = NA to the scale_fill_gradient argument.

```
map <- qplot(PolyCoordsY, PolyCoordsX, data=nh_geom, group=Poly_Name, fill = pc_nhwhite, geom="polygon", xlab = "", ylab = "", main = "New Haven") 
map + c_opts + scale_fill_gradient(name = "% White", na.value = NA)
```

[New Haven with excluded NAs](http://tinypic.com/r/e0ir6t/6)

Although this draws the NA blocks in white, it also excludes the polygon borders of the these blocks. Does anyone know how to keep the polygon outlines?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible dataset. Also, consider using `ggplot()` instead of `qplot()` as it is better for handling involved plotting tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a reproducible dataset, I can't test if this will work for your specific case.

Try passing a color to `na.value` like so:

```
scale_fill_gradient(name = "% White",na.value="white")
```

Comment: Using `ggplot()` instead of `qplot()` turned out to be a very good idea. I was able to come up with a satisfactory solution by adding a `geom_polygon()` argument after `ggplot` that subsets for the NAs: `ggplot(aes(PolyCoordsY, PolyCoordsX, group=Poly_Name, fill=pc_nhwhite), data=nh_geom, main = "New Haven") + geom_polygon() + c_opts + scale_fill_gradient(name = "% White", na.value = NA) + geom_polygon(aes(PolyCoordsY, PolyCoordsX, colour = NA), data = subset(nh_geom, is.na(pc_nhwhite)), fill = "white", alpha = 0.5, linetype = 1, col = "grey", cex = 0.25)`